# Alternatives to jQueryUI themeroller themes

Tags: jquery-ui, themes, themeroller

Everybody that uses jQueryUI will know of the themeroller, and I'm guessing a fair number of users share my opinion that themeroller themes are not the prettiest thing in the world.

Buttons are often impractically large, gradients look dull (no saturation changes), standard themes are more shiny than functional and the options for custom themes are...  limited. IMHO, themeroller themes look like [explitive].

There are a couple of custom themes I know of:

- Aristo http://taitems.github.com/Aristo-jQuery-UI-Theme/
- Absolution http://www.michaelvanderheeren.be/archives/382
- Bootstrap http://addyosmani.github.com/jquery-ui-bootstrap/
- jQUIT Builder http://jquit.com

I even tried my hand at creating my own: http://vanderlee.github.com/Afterdark/

http://www.primefaces.org/themes.html has a few other non-standard themes, but they seem mostly tweaked themeroller themes.

But this is very limited choice indeed and even these custom jQueryUI themes (including my own) often require modifications before being usable in a complex web application.

I'm wondering if there are any other custom jQueryUI themes around? In particular themes that don't follow the themeroller style, like Bootstrap's tabs or Absolution's dialogs.

Comment: Your afterdark and afternoon themes are pretty good! However other themes seem to be few and far between.

Answer (score 0):

There's [jQuery UI Bootstrap](http://addyosmani.github.com/jquery-ui-bootstrap/), as you can see on the project page:

> This project was started to bring the beauty and ease-of-use of Twitter Bootstrap to jQuery UI widgets ♥.

Answer (score 0):

There's my own try with jQuery UI Bootstrap, which you can see here: http://gustavohenke.github.io/jquery-ui-bootstrap